# Searching sub-directory for layouts in ASP.NET Core 7 MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net-core-mvc, asp.net-core-7.0

I have an ASP.NET Core 7 MVC app and my file structure for layouts looks like this:

[image]

In my `_ViewStart.cshtml` file, I have specified the layout to be:

```
@{
    Layout = $"~/Views/Shared/Layouts/_Main";
}
```

When running the project, it fails to find the layout and only when I append `.cshtml` to the end (like below) it works.

```
@{
    Layout = $"~/Views/Shared/Layouts/_Main.cshtml";
}
```

Is it possible to get the ASP.NET Core 7 MVC app to search particular folders for layouts? If so, how? I've searched online and can't find anything. It'd be great to not have to specify the file path too if that's also possible?

Answer (score 1):

> Is it possible to get the ASP.NET Core 7 MVC app to search particular
> folders for layouts?

Yes, it's possible. We can create a custom view engine and then supply the custom search locations to the new view engine. Using  [IViewLocationExpander](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.mvc.razor.iviewlocationexpander?view=aspnetcore-7.0)  to implement custom view engine.

Below is a work demo, you can refer to it.

CustomViewEngine:

```
 public class CustomViewEngine : IViewLocationExpander
 {
     public IEnumerable<string> ExpandViewLocations(ViewLocationExpanderContext context, IEnumerable<string> viewLocations)
     {

         yield return "~/Views/{1}/{0}.cshtml";            
         yield return "~/Views/Shared/Layouts/{0}.cshtml";
     }

     public void PopulateValues(ViewLocationExpanderContext context)
     {
         
     }
 }
```

In Program.cs add:

```
builder.Services.Configure<RazorViewEngineOptions>(o =>
{
    o.ViewLocationExpanders.Add(new CustomViewEngine());
});
```

In the ViewStart.cshtml:

```
@{
    Layout = "_Main";
}
```